# Сервер чата Tornado и как реализовать безболезненную перезагрузку сервера

Tags: python, redis, tornado

Привет! У меня есть чат, сообщения хранятся в объектах питона и потом выйгружаются в базу данных для хранения. Но дело в том, что если я сделал какую-то правку на сервере и решил перезагрузить то все данные пропадут разумеется, а это плохо.

Выход который мне сразу увиделся - это кеш, возможно, Redis. Но это же целый отдельный сервис, который будет работать и считай по сути такая же база данных. И как мне кажется нагрузку будет сильной с учётом отправки "прочёл сообщение" и сохранения этого статуса. И отсюда будут висяки при отправки сообщения, если много народу.

Скажите, пожалуйста, что в этом случаи делать? Я не прав и Redis будет очень быстро работать, почти ни чуть не медленнее чем хранить в объектах питона внутри памяти программы? Или какой-то ещё есть метод для решения данной задачи.

**Подскажите, как грамотнее применить кэш в данном случаи?**

Comment: Может проще перехватить sigterm и сбросить объекты в БД при завершении процесса

Comment: БД взорвётся наверное от такого массового сброса. Полагаю самое адекватное это всё-таки кэш. Но может кто-то подскажет как грамотнее его применить?

Comment: Зачем вам отдельный кэш? У вас и так, судя по всему, горячие данные уже в памяти. Считайте это кэшем. Вы можете синхронно писать в БД каждое изменение вашего кэша, и не терять данные, можете организовать слив по SIGTERM, как предложил @Mike, можете добавить отдельный тред, который будет вечно бегать, смотреть на грязные объекты в кэше, и писать их в БД. Какой вариант выбрать - зависит от профиля нагрузки. С кэшом в Редисе вы намучаетесь не меньше, особенно если отказаться от синхронной записи в БД.

Comment: Я делал кэш, потому что запросы к postgre блокирующая операция, и чат начинал глючить при большом объёме пользователей. Думаете если подключить к SIGTERM это не будет костылём? Типа при завершении процесса - сливать данные в базу (ничего не упадёт??) а при запуске загружать всё обратно в память?

Comment: Если использовать драйвер, например psycopg2 то для торнадо можно применять асинхронную обертку Momoko. С этой штукой создается пул соединений который можно расширять при больших очередях запросов. Momoko отлично работает в асинхронном потоко-безопасном режиме. Даже при долгих запросах хендлер торнадо готов принимать другие запросы и все работает достаточно шустро. Но, в любом случае pg, как и любая другая реляционная СУБД для реализации чата - плохой выбор в плане хайлоад.

Comment: Нашёл полезную статью по этой теме, кому интересно - кидаю ссылку: https://wezom.com.ua/blog/signalnyj-server-tornado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавьте обработчик SIGINT и SIGTERM;
2. Привяжите функцию сброса данных в БД к обработчику завершения;
3. Запускайте минимум 2 инстанса tornado с Nginx в роли балансировщика.

Как это будет работать:

- запускаются 2 и более инстанса приложения;
- при обновлении перезапускаете инстанцсы по очереди;
- при завершении сначала заблокируйте обработку новых запросов инстансом затем выполните процедуру сброса данных из памяти в БД.

В итоге получится плавная перезагрузка/обновление приложения, не заметная пользователям.

По поводу чата:

Redis гораздо эффективнее и надежнее в реализации функции простейшего мессенджера: статусы Online/Offline, сообщения персональные/групповые в связке WebSockets реализацией - будет очень быстро и с большим запасом прочности.
Если у вас очень много пользователей то лучше подключить к приложению RabbitMQ.

Comment: Но если запускать 2 инстанса, то тогда данные будут в разных процессах, верно?

Comment: Верно. Важно на стадии проектирования продумать механизмы передачи данных между инстансами, а лучше абстрагироваться по возможности вообще от хранения данных в не разделяемом варианте.  Не использовать сторонние сервисы для хранения общих данных при желании можно, если не планировать горизонтальное масштабирование. Например, как будет работать Ваш проект на 10 серверах в общей сложности в 150 одновременно запущенных экземплярах? Если заниматься разделением данных на уровне инстансов - это геморой. Redis самое простое что приходит на выручку, а если данных много и нужно круто - LevelDB.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Буду переходить на Redis!